# What is the meaning of `c`, `e`, and `s` in bignumber.js?

Tags: javascript, bignum, bignumber.js

What are the meanings of the `c`, `e`, and `s` fields in the object produced by `bignumber.js`?

For example:

```
> new BigNumber('1234')
{ c: [1234], e: 3, s: 1 }
> new BigNumber('12345678901234567890')
{ c: [123456, 78901234567890], e: 19, s: 1 }
```

Comment: They are well-documented on bignumber.js's [github page](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no research was done.

Comment: Looks like you mixed up the outputs?

Comment: @SamAxe that's not actually a close reason.

Comment: Ah okay, now that I know the answer, it's easy to search for "coefficient" in the docs. Without knowing that, though, it's not especially straight forward to search for, and google came up with nothing (except someone else asking the same question somewhere else, without an answer).

Comment: @JohnDvorak: sure it is.  You'll notice I was able to apply it to my close vote.

Comment: @SamAxe I mean, it's not a _valid_ close reason. That would be "duplicate", if that applies to this question.

Comment: @JohnDvorak: Today it appears to be a valid reason.

Comment: i think this question is valid. first i found via google from github was https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/ but didn't answer the question. what it is more, there are more repos than github. thanks to this open question I could find the solution, so I find it useful and quite straightforward. It saved me time, and thus have my positive vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- c |   coefficient   | number[]| Array of base 1e14 numbers
- e |   exponent      | number  | Integer, -1000000000 to 1000000000 inclusive
- s |   sign          | number  | -1 or 1

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: @Bergi [Properties](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#instance-properties) (note: i never used the library myself)

Comment: Thanks, you should [edit] your answer to include that link

Comment: How do you go back from BigNumber { s: 1, e: 18, c: [ 83897, 65512388205578 ] } to a regular number?